# Google Books API JSON object trouble

Tags: javascript, json, google-books

I am trying to pull from the Google Books API and insert the titles from the first 10 results into a web page. I have the site pulling the correct request and have the following callback function handling the results

```
function insert(books) {
    var list = books.items;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var title = list[i].title;
    var tag = "result" + i;
    var x = document.getElementById(tag);
    x.innerHTML = title;
    }
}
```

For ease lets suppose the following call was made

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Way of Kings&filter=partial&callback=insert"></script>
```

Right now it inserts the word "undefined" in every place it should insert a title. I can't find the error here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response data has `title` placed in a `volumeInfo` object.

Replace:

```
var title = list[i].title;
```

With:

```
var title = list[i].volumeInfo.title;
```

Comment: I see the volume info level now..... These objects need to be tabbed more agressively so I can see the levels more clearly!!! THANKS!

Comment: No problem! You could try using http://jsonlint.com/ , or a text editor that supports (auto-)formatting for JS / JSON. For what it's worth, here's a pastebin with the indented JSON: http://pastebin.com/CpMg92yg

Comment: I used jsonlint but admittedly I didnt include the json object in the check since i thought i had a grasp on the structure of the object and thought it must have been a syntax error i was missing..... oops

Comment: Oh i see what your saying, for help parsing a json object you can paste it in and it structures it better for you. Good tip.

Comment: Yea, it's nice for the formatting, if you don't have an IDE that can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` appears to be coming off of the `volumeInfo` object on the return collection.  This worked for me:

```
var title = list[i].volumeInfo.title;
```

Example:

https://jsbin.com/puyayamuwi/edit?html,output